# range in jinja2 inside a for loop

Tags: python, loops, jinja2

I have a nested list. I need to iterate through a list and keep it in for loop as shown below.

```
{% for alpha in list %}
    <div id="{{ loop.index }}"> 
       <div class='sidebar-one'>
          {% for beta in list[0][2:] %} #I want to iterate through list[0][2:] till list[n][2:]
              <p> {{ beta[0][0] }} </p>
          {% endfor %}
       </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried range but no luck.

```
{% for n in range(1,n) %}
{% for line in check[{{n}}][2:] %}
{% endfor %}
```

it threw error:

```
    TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

It's just like Python:

```
{% for n in range(n) %}
    {% for line in check[n][2:] %}
        <p> {{ beta[0][0] }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ok I get it. my mistake was putting that n into braces like {{n}} . I am still wondering why braces aren't used here? we are in jinja2 and not in python, right?

Comment: anohter query if you mind adding to the answer. how do I end first for loop and the second one? "endfor" will automatically take the nearer for loop right? I am wondering if there is any hack on ending outer for loop first and then the inner one!

Comment: @ChandanGupta: Jinja2 isn't Python, but its syntax is very similar. As for the loop thing, how would you do that with regular Python?

Comment: Thank you! Jinja and Python commands being similar is very useful.

Comment: Which of the inbuilt functions are allowed inside Jinja2 loops? (range is available, but afaik e.g. len is not)

Answer (score 15):

You can use the "length" property:

```
{% for n in range(yourList| length) %}
       <p class="someclass">{{n + 1}}.</p>
       <a class="someclass2" 
       href="{{ url_for( 'yourFunction', Int = yourList[n].iterable)}}">
       {{yourList[n].iterable}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Length is similar to len(yourlist) that we have in python.