# Range and url_for in jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

Good evening,

I'm trying to do a range function in a Jinja2 template and using the variable in a url_for function.

For example

```
{% for n in range(1, 6) %} 
   <a href="{{ url_for("static", filename="image[n].jpg") }}">Image {{n}}<a>       
{% endfor %}
```

and I would like my output to be:

```
<a href="image1.jpg">Image 1</a>
<a href="image2.jpg">Image 2</a>
<a href="image3.jpg">Image 3</a>
<a href="image4.jpg">Image 4</a>
<a href="image5.jpg">Image 5</a>
<a href="image6.jpg">Image 6</a>
```

I was following this link: [range in jinja2 inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691838/range-in-jinja2-inside-a-for-loop)

My output is as follows:

Image 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jinja2, the `+` operator concatenates strings. But that alone isn't enough, because `n` is an integer, not a string. You have to cast it to a string as well.

This should do the trick:

```
{% for n in range(1, 6) %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='image ' + n|string + '.jpg') }}">Image {{n}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```