# Python code in Flask's HTML curly braces don't work

Tags: python, flask

Whenever I try to write code in curly braces it doesn't work, shows error 404 page not found. I copied the code from 9:48 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIgPMguqyws&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-n4vJJybUVV3Un_NFS5EOgX&index=4).

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/<name>")
def home(name):
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Home Page!</h1>
    {% for x in range(10) %}
     {% if x % 2 == 1 %}
        <p>x</p>
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Also this is printed in the terminal below some other stuff which I think is why this is happening.

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'x' is undefined
```

Comment: Learn to use your browsers development tools so you can see what page it was looking for when you got the page not found error.

Comment: You may find the following answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691838/range-in-jinja2-inside-a-for-loop

Comment: The code you posted seems to be working on my browser. Is this your original code or just a part of it? Have you try changing the `<p>x</p>` line to `<p>{{x}}</p>` if you want to display the values of `x` in each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that I had several different terminals open and it seemed that I used an older version, where an error was in the code. To fix this, simply kill all of the active terminal instances and then run your script by opening a new terminal with VS Code -> Terminal -> New terminal or with Ctrl+Shift+`.

[How to kill active terminal instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqW8f.png)