# how to generate a list of continuous numbers in Jinja

Tags: jinja2

In Python we can use `for i in range(100)` to generate 100 continuous numbers, can we do the same in Jinja?

Comment: Yes, the `range` function is the same. Does this answer your question? [range in jinja2 inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691838/range-in-jinja2-inside-a-for-loop)

Comment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-globals.range

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for the info! It's weird that it didn't work in my case. Is this only available for Jinja2? how to check the version of Jinja?

Comment: Are you using Django maybe? People often mistakenly think the templating language of Django is Jinja when it is not, per default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/language/

Comment: If so, this is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates